# Missing ncurses header file

Tags: ncurses, fedora16

I am using *fedora16* in *vmware* but there is no **ncurses** header file. so i cannot practice with ncurses, how can I install ncurses header file.

Answer (score 0):

Fedora 16 is rather old, but if you can get to a workable yum server, you can install the ncurses-devel package to get the header files.

Answer (score 0):

Since you use fedora then doing the following installs ncurses on fedora:
First, go to [rpmfind.net](http://rpmfind.net) then search for ncurses and download the package according to your architecture. Then do the following to install the package:

```
rpm -i </Path/Package_name.extension>
```

Or alternatively, you can download the source code and compile it yourself by:

```
tar zxvf Ncurses_packageName.tar.gz
cd Ncurses_packageName
./configure
make
sudo make install
```